# invoking a javascript function on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I am currently on chart.gsp, I need to invoke a javascript function -filterResult() which is defined an external js file like monitoring.js.

Currently the filterResult() call is being made onclick event of button 'search' which is inside monitoring.gsp

I am getting my page forwarded to monitoring.gsp page, now how do I execute the filterResult() which is on button click in this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At end of page put a script block and call method in that block in monitoring.gsp

Like

> `<script> filterResult(); </script>`

Comment: Thanks, that does work nicely!, but I have another path in the app which invokes monitoring.gsp so I set a flag for my call and checked it on pageload to invoke filterResult(); I just tried to look your solution up somewhere, not finding it.. but last line in a file, if js script is automatically invoked?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. sorry i think i did not get your last question? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: just asking about documentation on the internet for your solution

Comment: i dont know where i last found it. But basically the browser executes anything in script block as it when it encounters if its not in a function. So this trick. Its also useful for auto loading or triggering a ajax background updates... The reason you want to put at end of page is so all your page is loaded and elements are loaded.